# javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext

Tags: jsp, jsf, jboss5.x

I'm trying a simple project to work on jboss, but I'm stuck at  this error  (I already tried using `.jsf` on the URL). the application in tomcat work's fine

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service

root cause

javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
 org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:425)
 org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:211)
 org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
 org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
 org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.faces.FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.faces.FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>faces-redirect-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>core.FacesRedirectFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>faces-redirect-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.1//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd">    

<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>resumeBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>core.ResumeBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>colorBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>core.ColorBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/customize.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>same-color</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/results/same-color.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/results/show-preview.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/customize-bg.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/results/show-preview2.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Not enough information. What is the URL you are trying to visit? What is the location/content of the file you expect it to resolve?
From your filter-mapping, it seems you should visiting an URL ending in '.faces' for the FacesServlet to handle the request (which includes the init of a FacesContext)

Answer (score 3):

> javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext

JSF components in the JSP page are complaining that the `FacesContext` cannot be found. The one responsible for creating this is the `FacesServlet`.

Here,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.faces.FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you've declared the `FacesServlet` to listen on an `url-pattern` of `*.faces`. So, to get the `FacesServlet` to run (and to create the `FacesContext`) you need to ensure that the request URL matches http://example.com/context/page.faces and thus *not* http://example.com/context/page.jsp.

If you rather want to use http://example.com/context/page.jsf, then you need to change the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` to `*.jsf`.

---

That said, the `FacesRedirectFilter` is suspicious as well. Isn't it redirecting `*.jsp` to `*.jsf` or so? If so, then you need to modify that filter as well. However, if the sole intent is to prevent users from accessing `*.jsp` files directly without involvement of `FacesServlet`, then better add the following security constraint to the `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to JSP files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

(and remove that `Filter`).

---

Unrelated to the problem, you mentioned JSF 1.2, but you've declared your `faces-config.xml` as JSF 1.1. Any JSF 1.2 implementation or newer will fall back to JSF 1.1 compatibility. You need to declare it as JSF 1.2 as well.

```
<faces-config version="1.2" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">
```

(and get rid of that `DOCTYPE`)