# HTTP 500 java.lang.RunTimeException Can't find FacesContext

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf, tomcat

I am getting this error HTTP 500 java.lang.RunTimeException Can't find FacesContext.

I read about this problem and most people adviced: 
to change from

```
http://localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/index.jsp
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/faces/index.jsp
```

I tried it but get the same error. Also, I have added all the recommended .jar files.

Error message:

[image]

When I chang the url at the end I get this error

[image]

Project setup:

[image]

web.xml file

[image]

faces-config.xml file

[image]

index.jsp file

[image]

employee.jsp file

[image]

Comment: Did you look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491703/javax-faces-facesexception-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-find-facescontext?rq=1

Comment: try this:
http://localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/index.faces

Comment: AAyush. I looked on the link you posted but if you notice my url pattern is /faces/* not .faces. I tried: http://localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/index.faces but I get the same error.

Comment: AAyush. When I use localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/index.face I get HTTP 404 error. Posted picture above.

Comment: Look at BaluC's answer. It is something with your web.xml file (Sorry I am no expert but experienced with some JSP stuff). If I were you I would put 
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354200/java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-find-facescontext?rq=1

Comment: I read that post and BaluC's explained well but you see my url pattern is not *.jsf only  /faces/* If I use his answer I would have to create  index.jsf file that is empty. It seems for me kind of tricky way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is if I remove everything that is in the index.jsp file between , including these tags, I am able to see the page. Otherwise I get the same error. One of the solutions was to use this url: localhost:8080/GeneratingEmployeeReport/faces/index.jsp I am not able to run the page directly. I am not sure why? I wish there is other solution